# Expand arguments passed to bash function that contains quotes

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to execute this curl command with the json body. I want to able to execute it with the help of a bash function such as 'query_db myId myClass'

```
function query_db(){
    curl -x socks5h://localhost:30001 -X POST https://my-db.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/my_db/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "eventData.clazz":   "'$2'"       }},
        { "match": { "eventData.itemId":   "'$1'"       }}
      ]
  }
}
}'
}
```

However, the above query fails because $2 and $1 is not expanded into the actual arguments. How do I fix this function?

Comment: Why do you think `$2` and `$1` are not expanded? They are unquoted (not a [good practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)) and the shell should expand them. What tests did you do?

Answer (score 0):

It actually does work. It just breaks if the arguments contain spaces, though (and it breaks differently if they contain characters that are special in JSON), but the general usage of `'text'$var'text'` is correct.

To fix just the spaces issue, put double-quotes around each variable expansion: (the existing double quotes are just literal characters inside the single-quoted string literal, so they do nothing for the variable expansion)

```
' ...
    { "match": { "eventData.clazz":   "'"$2"'"       }},
    { "match": { "eventData.itemId":  "'"$1"'"       }}
... '
```

But to *properly* fix all issues, you'll need to use some tool that actually understands how to generate JSON, and not just generic string substitution:

```
function query_db(){
    local json="$(jq --null-input --arg class "$2" --arg item "$1" '{
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "eventData.clazz": $class } },
            { "match": { "eventData.itemId": $item } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }')"

    curl -x socks5h://localhost:30001 -X POST https://my-db.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/my_db/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "$json"
}
```

(The `$class` and `$item` are now jq variables, not bash variables, and will be automatically expanded into string values.)